# properties of "plane curves" in the sphere $ S^2$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Just as there is a version of the theorem Jordan curve in $S^2$,
will exist a version of the isoperimetric inequality?

Would greatly appreciate any reference

Comment: There's a short paragraph in wikipedia on the isoparametric inequality on $\mathbb S^2$. Is that what you want? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#The_isoperimetric_inequality_on_the_sphere